# Nextjs App doesn't work in production only in dev mode, return 500 error from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have an app that works really well in dev mode and even in the build mode of Next js, the repo is there: https://github.com/Sandrew94/space-tourism.

i think the problems is where i get the access_token from firebase in getServerSideProps for strange reason in devMode works and in production don't.

I have follow this guide to get that results https://colinhacks.com/essays/nextjs-firebase-authentication

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    const cookies = nookies.get(context);

    const { token } = cookies;

    const planetInfo = await fetchPlanetsInfo("destinations", token);

    return {
      props: {
        data: planetInfo || [],
      },
    };

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  } catch (e) {

    context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/" });
    context.res.end();

  
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/",
      },
      props: {} as never,
    };
  }
};
```

or in the context

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<any>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return auth.onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        setUser(null);
        nookies.set(undefined, "token", "", { path: "/" });
      } else {
        const token = await user.getIdToken();
        setUser(user);
        nookies.set(undefined, "token", token, { path: "/" });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  // force refresh the token every 10 minutes
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handle = setInterval(async () => {
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      console.log(user);
      if (user) await user.getIdToken(true);
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000);

    // clean up setInterval
    return () => clearInterval(handle);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

it's so annoying this thing, it works good in devMode i don't know what's changes in production mode.

/////////////////////////////

UPDATE 1

I have done some tests, it seems like the cookie isn't set properly and return undefined ( i check with some console.log) also i get a warning maybe this is the problem

```
The "token" cookie does not have a valid value for the "SameSite" attribute. Soon cookies without the "SameSite" attribute or with an invalid value will be managed as "Lax". This means that the cookie will no longer be sent to third-party contexts. If the application depends on the availability of this cookie in this type of context, add the "SameSite = None" attribute. For more information on the "SameSite" attribute, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
```

Comment: You should **NOT** share the Admin SDK credentials unlike the Firebase config used on client side. Instead can you check the browser console and share what errors do you see there apart from just 500\?

Comment: Many things will not work in production that works in dev. When you build a next site, it builds every page and all code must work, essentially. Not to mention production bundling, production versions of libraries, etc. Start by debugging the problem and trying to get an error message. If you can't, then delete code until you notice what causes the failure, and post back here.

Comment: i have done some check it seems like the cookie isn't being set, i update the posts above with the warning i get